# Getting error while deploying node.js cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, firebase-notifications

I am implementation notifications of firebase in my app.
**This is my node.js function**

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin=require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotificaiton=functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{userKey}/{notification_id}').
onWrite(event => {
const userKey = event.params.userKey;
const notification = event.params.notification;

console.log('The userKey is ', userKey);

});
```

My firebase db structure is 
[image]

Error in Functions is

[image]

Please help me . 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code

**From this**

```
exports.sendNotificaiton=functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{userKey}/{notification_id}').
onWrite(event => {
const userKey = event.params.userKey;
const notification = event.params.notification;

console.log('The userKey is ', userKey);

});
```

**To this**

```
exports.sendNotificaiton=functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{userKey}/{notification_id}').onWrite((change, context) => {

const userKey = context.params.userKey;
const notification = context.params.notification;

console.log('The userKey is ', userKey);

});
```

You are using the old `event` trigger for `onWrite()`, now you need to pass context and your dataSnapshot (change).

Also `onWrite` has `before` and `after` values when a write event triggers your database

check the docs here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events?hl=en

See the notification example on github for notifications: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/fcm-notifications